# No Longer Able to Tag Folders in SharePoint Online

Tags: folder, metadata, tags

I realized today that as of VERY recently (the last couple weeks), I am no longer able to add tags/metadata to folders. Files still have tagging ability, but not folders. I am working in SharePoint Online (Office 365) and this is happening in all of my Site Collections, although I'm not sure yet if it is happening across my whole tenant.
Is anyone else experiencing this?

Sylvie

Comment: Are these custom folders? I.e. new Content Types created from the base folder type? If not, what do you mean by "tagging"? Tags and Notes?

Comment: Are you working with the Modern UI? Do you see a classic UI "LIBRARY" ribbon?

Comment: Hi Mike, 
They're not custom folders, they're the standard content type. By tagging I just mean adding metadata. Even the "Title" field is no longer editable, only the "Name" field can be edited. For example, we have several columns of managed metadata, free text fields and enterprise keywords. None of these are available anymore on folders. 
I am working with the Modern UI, but I also switched back to the "classic sharepoint" and it was the same, no tagging. 
Thanks!

Comment: Update: it looks like I am able to edit the metadata properties using "Quick Edit" - but I still don't understand why I can't do it any other way, and why the default values are not attaching to folders. I need folders to automatically get default values for a couple columns. Basically, I just need the regular functionality of default values in site columns.

Comment: I must be missing something here... Out of the box library folders have only one editable property, "Name". You can copy the default Folder Content Type and add metadata columns. Clicking "New Folder" adds a default folder while clicking the "New" dropdown menu lets you add a custom folder. You can also create Document Set Content Types (which are based on folders) and add metadata columns. These are also added to a library from the "New" dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

you would be able to change folder metadata by clicking on button "Quick edit" from menu. There you can change values for all folders at once